# SQL Server Windows Auth Login sees Domain as untrusted

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, active-directory, sql-server-2008, domain-controller

I've had someone set up a domain controller on windows 2008 on one server, and sql server 2008 on another. The domain seems to be working fine, I'm logged on as a domain user on both servers, nothing seems to be a problem there.

However, when I try to add a domain user/group to SQL Server Security (e.g. clicking ok from the create login screen) it says it can't find it (even though I've used the search to find the correct account in the first place), when I try to logon (even though I haven't added it yet) it says something about the account being part of an untrusted domain instead of saying I don't have permission to log on.

Anyone have any ideas on what is set up incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a. Check that the user account the SQL Server service is running as a domain account.
[From MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504.aspx)

> If the service must interact with
>   network services, access domain
>   resources like file shares or if it
>   uses linked server connections to
>   other computers running SQL Server,
>   you might use a minimally-privileged
>   domain account. Many server-to-server
>   activities can be performed only with
>   a domain user account. This account
>   should be pre-created by domain
>   administration in your environment.

b. Ensure the DNS server being used by the member server knows about the domain, i.e. can resolve SRV records for AD services.  See this [blog post](http://codespin.blogspot.com/2008/01/fix-for-inability-to-select-domain.html) for more information.

c. Follow [resolution steps in the MS KB article.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324321/en-us)

Comment: They are dynamic, this is just a test atm so I haven't bother to assigned static addresses. They haven't changed though. Why would this cause the problem... they can see each other without a problem, domain can be resolved fine, dns and domain controller are same machine.
I don't quite understand why I'm having this problem in the first place...

Comment: have a dynamic ip isnt the cause, but sometimes in soho setup's the pesky router's DHCP will assign its own DNS server which can be a problem.

Comment: I've got DNS forwarding setup, so that isn't causing a problem, what weird is everything seems find, except for adding logons to sql server. for example, when I enter the name in the login box and click search, the dialog appears and lets me seach my domain without problem, I can choose who I want, click ok, name appears in the login name textbox e.g. "domain\user" I set the mappings click ok, then get an error message saying it can't find the "domain\user".

Comment: ive updated my answer to be more complete

Comment: you've got dns forwarding setup where?

Comment: on my domain controller - it needs this otherwise nothing works