# SQL 2008 network logon

Tags: active-directory, sql

I have a domain controller that I have installed active directory onto and have set up an account that I want to use for my SQL server installation on another computer that is linked onto the domain.

I can search for the account in active directory and I am able to select it into the add new user section in MSSMS, however, when I click add I get 'Windows NT user or group 'DOMAIN\user' not found. Check the name again. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 15401)

I have googled the Error code and I haven't found a solution that has fixed the error.

If you have any help I would be grateful.

Comment: so when you say linked into the domain r u saying its a member of the domain?

Comment: yes. the client is a member of my domain. I can see all of the members of my active directory in the MSSMS interface but cannot add any as a windows authenticated user.

Comment: I should say my client is going to be my application server

Comment: Are on a Hypervisor ?

Answer (score 1):

make sure that the DNS server for the NIC on the sql server box points to the domain controller.  You may be having problems resolving the domain.

The alternate (ugly) way to fix this may be to use [LMHOSTS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314108).

Comment: I have had to log on as the local administrator to the SQL box as Im alos having some permissions issuses with my netowrk account. I think that i am having problems resolving the domain. how would I make the domain controller accessable to my SQL box.

Comment: follow the answers I've given here: http://serverfault.com/questions/145466  its basically the same problem